# Does SysTick_Handler() have to be in main file?

Tags: arm, lpc1768, cmsis

Does the CMSIS `SysTick_Handler()` have to be placed in the main file (i.e., the same file where it is configured)?

If not, how would I go about placing it elsewhere? Is it just a matter of defining the function in another `.cpp file`, and including "LPC17xx.h"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put it anywhere, as long as it has the right linkage spec the linker will take care of it for you.

You don't need any header included, just `extern "C" void SysTick_Handler(){ ... }` in an implementation file.

Comment: That extern "C" part is really important. I was hung up on that for quite a while when I first started out. You don't need it if you are in C since the compiler was specified the interrupt handler names in C. But if you are in C++, function name mangling will occur if you do not use those keywords causing the compiler to be unable to not recognize the function's name as the interrupt handler. You'll get no warnings if you don't. Your interrupt will just inexplicably not work since the compiler just treats it as a regular function and use the default interrupt dummy handler.

Comment: @Toor Can Systick_Handler() be made a member of a class? If so, does it need to be static? Ideally I'd like it to have access to context data, without needing a "load" function in the same file, which initialises variables in an included header file.

Comment: @19172281 Not easily, no. A member function has an inherent this pointer passed to it as the first argument, which can't happen if it's called from elsewhere. The easiest thing to do is have your `SysTick_Handler` call a function on an instance of your class.

Comment: @Colin, that's what I wanted to do originally, but what's the best way to get the instance to the handler in the first place?

Comment: I don't know of a way to make the handler a class member. I would not be surprised if you could not. I write public member functions if my interrupt handler needs to access them. You could try declaring the handler as a friend to your class rather than declaring it as a class member. That might work but I've never tried it. Let me know if it works. It could be convenient if it does.

Comment: @19172281 https://gist.github.com/csowter/73ce695d1c304c064f9a746d580f39e1 I have uploaded a systick handler from one of my projects there, when you create an instance of it, it initialises the pointer in the unnamed namespace which can then be used by the IRQ handler. It should probably be a singleton, but I just don't create two of them.

Comment: Seems like an interesting way of doing things. What is the purpose of the namespace? Is it needed?

Comment: It's not necessary, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/357404/why-are-unnamed-namespaces-used-and-what-are-their-benefits answers it better than I could here.

Comment: And finally, is there any reason why I couldn't place the pointer to systickTimer in the header file?

Comment: It's best not to, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38942013/declaring-variables-in-header-files-c

Comment: This would only be an issue though if I included the systickTimer header file more than once (directly)?

Answer (score 1):

It does not. I have it in a separate .cpp file dedicated to SysTick code. It's not even declared in the .h file associated with that .cpp file. The compiler will search it out, wherever it is. This is true for all the interrupt handler function names.